# How to use var more than once in linq?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, linq

```
var ID, x,y

switch(ItemTypeNo)
{

   case ItemType.A : 

    ID = from s in cntx.Tablo1
break;


   case ItemType.B : 

    ID = from s in cntx.Tablo2
break;


   case ItemType.C : 

    ID = from s in cntx.Tablo3
break;

}
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking, but you can't do your first line `var ID, x, y;` - when you use var you need to give the compiler enough context to work out the variable types there and then. This means that if you're forward-declaring a variable you have to specify the real type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use `var` for inline initialization, which that isn't. You would need to type `ID` appropriately, and since `var` has a *single* type that would only work if `Tablo1`, `Tablo2` and `Tablo3` are the same type (which seems unlikely).

What is it you need to do here?

There *is* a scenario that works here; when *selecting* a common type from each; let's assume thay all have an `int` primary key:

```
IQueryable<int> ids;    
switch(ItemTypeNo)
{    
   case ItemType.A : ids= from s in cntx.Tablo1 select s.Id; break;
   case ItemType.B : ids= from s in cntx.Tablo2 select s.Id; break;
   case ItemType.C : ids= from s in cntx.Tablo3 select s.Id; break;
   default: throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

However, in the general case... not so much. You could type `ID` as the non-generic `IQueryable`, but to be honest that doesn't let you do very many interesting things. And `dynamic` doesn't play nicely with LINQ (and even if it did, it would be a hack here).

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous type "var" can not be declared without having it initialized.
Once "var" is initialized (once it is inferred from usage), it can't be altered throughout the course of its lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare ID as `IQueryable` as this is base type for generic `IQueryable<T>`